# How to use eval in the program

Tags: javascript, html, eval

I am developing a javascript program -- graphing calculator. User inputs an equation (like x*x+2*x ) into text field, presses "get answer" button and should get a graph. If I write in function f(x) an expression, like "Math.sin(x)" it works great, but when I try to use eval method to evaluate the users code, the program stops working. I'm new to javascript. Any help would be appreciated!
JavaScript code

```js
//vars
var points = "";
var input = document.querySelector("#input");
var evaluate = document.querySelector("#evaluate");

evaluate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.appendChild(makeSVG(svgData));
});

function f(x) {
  return eval('(function() { x=' + x + ';' + input.value + ';}())');
}

function getPoints() {
  for (var i = -10; i < 10.0; i += 0.25) {
    var x = 10 * i + 100;
    var y = -10 * f(i) + 100;
    points += "" + x + "," + y + " ";
  }
  return points;
}

var svgData = [{
    type: 'svg',
    data: {
      viewBox: "0 0 500 200"
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'polyline',
    data: {
      fill: "none",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: "1",
      points: getPoints()
    }
  },
];

function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v) {
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) {
      return "-" + m.toLowerCase();
    }), v[p]);
  }
  return n
}

function makeSVG(data) {
  var result;
  data.forEach(
    function(elem, index, array) {
      if (index)
        result.appendChild(getNode(elem.type, elem.data));
      else
        result = getNode(elem.type, elem.data);
    }
  );
  return result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Graphing Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Graphing Calculator</h1>
  <form>
    <input id="input" type="text">
    <button id="evaluate" type="button">Get answer</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what error message are you getting? Also, [there are security issues with `eval`](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/94017/47451)

Comment: You don't need an IIFE in `f()`.

Comment: The IIFE doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: At first I thought about eval('x='+x+'; '+expressionFromTextField) , but I was told that eval method should have parenthesis, so this distracted me and I rewrote the eval to function. In Eclipse IDE I don't get any errors, the program just doesn't display the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the IIFE in `f()`. Just call `eval(x)`. It will execute in the scope of `f()`, so it can access `x`.

Another problem is that you're calling `getPoints()` when you initialize `svgData`, but the user hasn't yet filled in the input field. You need to do that in the click handler.

```js
//vars
var points = "";
var input = document.querySelector("#input");
var evaluate = document.querySelector("#evaluate");

evaluate.addEventListener('click', function() {
  svgData[1].data.points = getPoints();
  document.body.appendChild(makeSVG(svgData));
});

function f(x) {
  return eval(input.value);
}

function getPoints() {
  for (var i = -10; i < 10.0; i += 0.25) {
    var x = 10 * i + 100;
    var y = -10 * f(i) + 100;
    points += "" + x + "," + y + " ";
  }
  return points;
}

var svgData = [{
    type: 'svg',
    data: {
      viewBox: "0 0 500 200"
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'polyline',
    data: {
      fill: "none",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: "1",
      points: null
    }
  },
];

function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v) {
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(m, p, o, s) {
      return "-" + m.toLowerCase();
    }), v[p]);
  }
  return n
}

function makeSVG(data) {
  var result;
  data.forEach(
    function(elem, index, array) {
      if (index)
        result.appendChild(getNode(elem.type, elem.data));
      else
        result = getNode(elem.type, elem.data);
    }
  );
  return result;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Graphing Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Graphing Calculator</h1>
  <form>
    <input id="input" type="text">
    <button id="evaluate" type="button">Get answer</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to adapt this code, but I still don't get a graph, when I execute the program. What I get is just a blank space one after another (after each click on button). When I write an expression directly to eval, I get a graph, but when I use input.value, I get nothing

Comment: You're calling `getPoints()` when you initialize `svgData`, not when the user clicks on the button. `input.value` is empty then.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `eval` should always be used carefully as it allows arbitrary code execution from users input. In your case it can't really be harmful because it only allows a user to execute code on his own page.

Your `f()` function contains an `eval` which contains a needless self-executing function. Moreover, this self-executing function doesn't return anything. Try this instead:

```
function f(x) {
  return eval(input.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! My program passes x value from a for loop to the function, eval is supposed to return the value of y for each x. How can I include x into the eval method?

Comment: It is "included" in my solution. `eval` can access the `f()` execution context which contains `x`

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't get a graph, when I execute the program. What I get is just a blank space one after another. When i write an expression directly to eval, I get a graph, but when I use input.value, I get nothing

Comment: You should review your code, it actually doesn't make sense. You are calling `getPoints` when you build `svgData` which calls `f` several times way before the user can type any input.

Comment: Yeah, I did have this problem. Thank you very much for help!